# Error in tidyLPA: "Error in UseMethod("get_data", x) : no applicable method for 'get_data' applied to an object of class "c('bestLPA', 'list')""

Tags: tidyverse, tidyr, tidymodels, tidy

```
library(tidyLPA)

prism2 <- prism %>%
  select(cars1, cars2, cars3, cars4, cars5, ihp1, ihp2, ihp3, ihp4, ihp5, oiq1, 
         oiq2, oiq3, oiq4, oiq5, oiq6, oiq7, oiq8, sms1, sms2, sms3, sms4, sms5,
         sms6) %>%
  single_imputation() %>%
  scale() %>%
  estimate_profiles(1:7, variances = "equal", covariances = "zero") %>%
  compare_solutions(statistics = c("AIC", "BIC"))

prism_out <- tidyLPA::get_data(prism2) %>%
  tidyr::gather(Class_prob, Probability, contains("CPROB"))
```

When running an LPA using tidyLPA I am unable to use get_data and am met with the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("get_data", x) :
> no applicable method for 'get_data' applied to an object of class "c('bestLPA', 'list')"

I am wondering if anyone else has run into this issue and what the solution was?

I uninstalled and reinstalled tidyLPA with no success.

Comment: I have not used this package, however, looking over the documentation, the `get_data` function expects an object of class ` tidyLPA` or `tidyProfile`.  Have you tried passing the object returned by `estimate_profiles` to `get_data` instead of the list produced by the compare function?